# How to use sgi hash_table in VS2005?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, sgi

I wrote a C++ project in VS2005, and used lots of STL container with its plus-in STL. However, I found STL in VS2005 does not have a hash_map in it, I want to use SGI hash_map. How can I change my project to use SGI STL?

Thanks for Brian's method, it works! And it's simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2005 does have a hash_map:

```
#include <hash_map>
stdext::hash_map
```

If you still want to though you can [download the sgi stl here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/download.html).  You should be able to just set the include directory to the sgi location.  It will take precedence over the VC++ global include directories.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if VS2005 has TR1, but if it has (or if you later decide to use another compiler which has it), you can use `unordered_map`:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
std::tr1::unordered_map mymap;
```

Also, for completeness, GCC (which used to have `<hash_map>`) has `hash_map` on `<ext/hash_map>` (on a different namespace). On recent GCC releases, you can also use `<tr1/unordered_map>`.